# How to control what indicator apps run

Tags: transparency, gnome2

Recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and then discovered that I can change the background of the gnome-panel (I'm a gnome guy and using flashback to have the old gnome2 stuff running, thus gnome-panel). Looks great however on one of my machines (desktop) some of the indicators are opaque while the rest of the panel is transparent.

[opaque indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD3zd.png)

However, on my laptop (also running Ubuntu 20.04) even this is transparent. So I'm trying to "fix" my desktop as I prefer the transparent look.

From what I can tell these are indicator apps like:

- indicator-application-service
- indicator-bluetooth-service
- indicator-session-service
- indicator-sound-service

It seems the indicator-application-service is the wrapper for the opaque part (indicator-session-service and indicator-sound-service are contained therein). So one question I have is why does indictor-application-service pay attention to the transparent background I set for the whole gnome-panel on one system but not my laptop?

Additionally, it would seem there should be some way of configuring what indicator apps run and which do not. For example, I don't want nor need the bluetooth-service on my desktop - it's so old that I don't think it even has support for bluetooth! Plus I've found and killed some of these indicator apps for print notification and the like - things I just don't use. But how would I configure these indicator apps to say "X, Y and Z run here but not A, B nor C" at startup?

TIA